# Getting Error while replaying Oracle Application script using JMeter

Tags: oracle, jmeter, oracleforms

I have successfully recorded EBS oracle application script using JMeter

There are 208 number of request in my script.

But I am getting below error at step # 114 when I am replaying the script.

At step #111 I am getting JSession ID in response code, so I have correlated that JSession ID and replace this JSessionID in the subsequent request(Step 112, Step 113, Step 114).

> ifError:6/Forms session <62> aborted: unable to communicate with
>   runtime process.

I have attached error screenshot for your ease of.

[image]

I am unable to understand this error. I mean is there any Correlation error or what kind of error is it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a message usually indicates a synchronization error between the Oracle Forms client and server. In Forms you don't only need to have a proper session ID but you have to encrypt messages with the proper key previously negotiated with the server, so (test) automation can't be performed by simply replying previously recorded packets (they are encrypted with an obsolete key).

You can find more information on these links:

https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/testing/automated-security-testing-oracle-forms-applications-35970

https://github.com/v-p-b/oracle_forms